# Wildcard path mapping /A/* should return 404 when path info is absent like /A

Tags: servlets, wildcard, url-pattern, pathinfo

I am new in Servlets. I am trying to map a URL using the **wildcard (*)**, but it's not working the way i expected.

Here is my servlet class.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/A/*"})
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().write("Working...");
    }
}
```

The above servlet is working for both **example.com/A** and **example.com/A/car**.
I want to work the servlet only for the the second option which is **example.com/A/whatEver**. How can i do that ?

In simple:  I just want to work the servlet if there's anything after **example.com/A**.

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: it should work, what is the error your getting.?

Comment: No error, but it's working for both the urls. I just want to work the servlet if there's anything after **example.com/A**.

Comment: you mean to say it should work for example.com/a/* is it.?

Comment: The path is always relative to your web application context, typically this is the same as your project name: `example.com/<contextPath>/A/*`...

Comment: then you can use example.com/a*

Comment: @iHappyk : It should work **only for** example.com/a/*

Comment: That's not possible via mapping URL pattern alone. How exactly do you want `example.com/A` to behave? Then we can post an answer for that.

Comment: @home : The deployment root is fine.All other components working perfectly.

Comment: @BalusC : The **TestServlet**  should only work when there's something after the **example.com/A/**, like **A/car** , **A/bat**, **A/cat/bat/rat**, is it possible? . The problem is it's still working even if there's nothing but just **example.com/A**

Comment: Yes. I already understand that part. I didn't ask that. I asked you how exactly the servlet should behave when `example.com/A` without pathinfo is requested. Should it return a 404 not found or so? Or should it forward to a specific resource? Etc. Then it's simply a matter of writing that code in servlet accordingly. Or, if this servlet is beyond your control, then via a filter.

Comment: a 404 would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just invoke [`HttpServletResponse#sendError()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus-int-) with [`SC_NOT_FOUND` (404)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#SC_NOT_FOUND) when [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo--) is null or [empty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--) or [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) to `/`.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();

    if (pathInfo == null || pathInfo.isEmpty() || pathInfo.equals("/")) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        return;
    }

    // ... (continue)
}
```